# Yammer REST API search query syntax

Tags: api, rest, search, yammer

I'm trying to get started with Yammer API. I have been able to go through the oauth process and obtain the token. Now, I just want to perform searches within the current user's account.

The Yammer REST documentation states that I need to query against this url:
    https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/search.json

What I don't know is how to provide the query and what the query syntax is. I would really appreciate it if someone could help me with the correct syntax to provide the following:

1. The search query
2. The access token

For example, would I need something like (the syntax below is not working for me):

```
https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/search.json?search=marketing&token=abcd1234
```

As always, I would appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Do you get an error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make a GET request to `https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/search.json?search=marketing` and specify the OAuth token on the Authorization header in the following format:

```
Authorization: Bearer abcd1234
```

When you do this you'll get JSON back with the search results.

The ability to specify the OAuth token on the URL is no longer supported.

Comment: Thanks Brian. I just realized this myself and got it to work as you mentioned above. I had missed that minor detail in the Yammer API docs but finally got it to work. Works just fine now. Thanks.